# track recipient IP address through mail inphp

Tags: php, email

I want to find the IP address of recipient whom I sent a mail after opening it. I can tract down whether he has open my email or not but not getting proper IP address of the client.

In my php code I have created a dynamic image path to track the IP address.

```
 <img border="0" height="150" src="http://www.ogmaconceptions.com/tracking.php?email=<?php echo $client_email?>" width="100" />
```

And in my tracking.php I have used this code to track IP and create image dynamically.

```
public function getRealIP() {
        $ipaddress = '';
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])) {
            $ipaddress =  $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
        } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'])) {
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
        }
        else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

        return $ipaddress;
    }

function LoadJpeg($imgname)
{
    /* Attempt to open */
    $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imgname);

    /* See if it failed */
    if(!$im)
    {
        /* Create a black image */
        $im  = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 30);
        $bgc = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $tc  = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

        imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 150, 30, $bgc);

        /* Output an error message */
        imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5, 'Error loading ' . $imgname, $tc);
    }

    return $im;
}
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$img = LoadJpeg('images/OC-logo.jpg');

imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

I am getting the IP but the IP of Email server of recipient, not the actual IP address of the recipient. Is there any tricks so that I can get the client IP as well.

Thanks
Amar

Answer (score 1):

THANKS TO MAIL PROVIDERS, spammers cannot track user IPs anymore. **Privacy** nowadays is not that silly thing as it used to be.

Precautions already taken, either in standalone and online mail clients

Answer (score 0):

dude

you should just read the

```
<?php
$client_ip = getHostByAddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
?>
```

and dont put it inside nested IF,
that way you will be able to get the client's ip then.. ^_^